# Interactive shell mechanism with MacRuby/XCode

Tags: ruby, xcode, shell, interface-builder, macruby

I have the following noobie class:

```
class CoreController < NSWindowController
  attr_accessor :consoleOutput, :consoleInput, :command, :parsedcommand

  def showInConsole_clicked(sender)
    x = `"#{@consoleInput.stringValue()}"`
    @consoleOutput.stringValue = x
    @command.stringValue = @consoleInput.stringValue()
    @parsedcommand.stringValue = x
  end

end
```

The interface that belongs to this controller basically reads from an inputbox and routes its data to a shell statement. It works, but not as cool as I would want it to be.

I can use '**ls**' for example, with no problems. However, when I create longer commands such as '**ls -l**' or '**ruby -v**', it is almost like nothing really happened. Anyone a clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the double-quotes in this line:

```
x = `"#{@consoleInput.stringValue()}"`
```

If you type **ruby-v**, that will be executed but if you type `"ruby -v"`, that will fail because no executable called **"ruby -v"**, exits as there is only **ruby**. Remove the quotes and it will work.